# How to refresh Jquery Data-table after event performed in angular 6

Tags: angular, datatable

**HTML**

```
<table  datatable id="tblProjects" [dtOptions]="dtOptions"   [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  class="table row-border hover" *ngIf="this.temp_var">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Project Name</th>
                  <th>Status </th>
                  <th>Download</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let project of projects">
                  <td>{{ project.sProjectrName}}</td>
                  <td  *ngIf="project.isActive"> Active </td>
                  <td  *ngIf="!project.isActive"> In Active</td>
                  <td><a rel="nofollow" href="http://localhost:8090/download/{{project.iCustomerID}}/{{project.iProjectID}}">File</a></td>
                  <td><a rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0)"  (click)="deleteProject(project.iProjectID)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ><span class="i-text">Delete</span></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Componet.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataTablesModule, DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Project } from '../project';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ControlPosition } from '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projectlist',
  templateUrl: './projectlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projectlist.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectlistComponent implements OnInit {
  fileUrl;
  public temp_var: Object=false;
  projects: Project[];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,private customerService : CustomerService,private sanitize : DomSanitizer) { 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    const customerId = sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
     processing: true
   };
     this.customerService.getprojectList(customerId).subscribe(data => {
     this. projects=data;
      this.temp_var=true;
    });
  }
  deleteProject(projectId)
  {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/delete/'+projectId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        window.location.reload();
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      ); 
  }

}
```

I have integrated j Query Data table in my Angular 6 application,i want to know How to refresh j Query data table in angular 6 app after event performed like delete and update records In Data table I'm going to delete project in the table i need to refresh i have tried many ways to do this.if any one know the answer please update

Comment: I would recommend you to use material table in angular rather than jquery table

Comment: You should *not* need to reload the page as shown in your code. With Angular, if you modify the underlying bound data structures, the UI will **automatically** update to match. So after the delete you can either remove the item from the list or reget fresh data. In either case, if you keep the `projects` structure updated it will appear correctly in the list.

Answer (score 0):

'datatable="ng"' use this attribute on your table tag Or

follow this two link, and use rerender method of angular-datatables

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/rerender

Answer (score 0):

You have not taken the stream back from server after deletion,

way 1. Get the new project data after the get(i am assuming you are performing the delete in this api) and reassign the projects variable,

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/delete/'+projectId)
  .subscribe(res => {
    // assuming res returns updated list of projects
    this.projects = res.projects;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

way 2: you could have used the delete method of the REST end point and performed the same operation given above in way 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/delete/'+projectId)
    .subscribe(res => {
    this.projects.length = 0 // use this before getting response
    this.projects = res.projects;
    $('#tblProjects').DataTable().destroy // use these two lines after getting response <--------
    this.dtTrigger.next()
    }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    }
    );
```